# Search items I have placed in a linear layout that contain buttons custom text on Android Search

Tags: android, xml, search

I want to search items I have placed in a linear layout that contain buttons and I want them to appear as defined in the layout with the buttons and the styling I have defined. I have tried to use the list view but the items only appear as text in a list view, with no extra components.I attached an image showing my layout and my searchBar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESzWx.png

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by placing a single card view with the styles i desire on XML a list layout and i implemented variables on my java main Activity class with the appropriate names for each item.

`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
        android:background="#EFEFEF"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_column="0"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold">

                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Over 700 items in store!"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold">

                        </TextView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#FF0000">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="ON SALE !"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textStyle="bold">

                            </TextView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/checkout_button"
                            android:onClick="groceries_click"
                            android:text="shop now!"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textSize="12dp">

                        </Button>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Below is my java method contained within the onCreate class

```
names = new ArrayList<>();

    names.add("Fruit, Veg & Frozen");
    names.add("Meat, Poultry & Fish");
    names.add("Bread, Bakery & Desserts");
    names.add("Dairy, Eggs & Milk");
    names.add("Beverages & Juice");
    names.add("Grains, Cereals & Spices");
    names.add("Household Cleaning");
    names.add("Canned & Dried Foods");
    names.add("Clothing");
    names.add("Women's Fashion");
    names.add("Men's Fashion");
    names.add("Girls's Fashion");
    names.add("Boy's Fashion");
    names.add("Baby");
    names.add("Strollers & Pregnancy");
    names.add("Care & Feeding");
    names.add("Electronics");
    names.add("Software");
    names.add("Computers");
    names.add("Home & Kitchen");
    names.add("Pet Supplies");
    names.add("Luggage");
    names.add("Sports");
    names.add("Outdoors");
    names.add("DIY");
    names.add("Games");
    names.add("Boy's Toys");
    names.add("Girl's Toys");
    names.add("Video Games");
```